# filter a query based on multiple list boxes in a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, filter, listbox, vba

I have an Access database with two tables: "contacts" and "country"
These contain a number of fields in each.

I have a query, "Filter", that brings these two tables together.

I want to create a form with as many list boxes as there are fields in the query. A user can open the form and select multiple data from each list box - the row sources are tied back to the two tables above. Then on the click of a button the query would be displayed and filters would be applied dependent on the users selections in the list boxes. If nothing is selected then the query is displayed without filters. Similarly the user is not required to make selections from all the list boxes.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have lifted some code from other websites which has allowed me to apply filters for a single list box. The difficulty is expanding for multiple list boxes. Is this an absurd request??

PS I can post my existing code however I believe that this is now a 'red herring' and would be best starting fresh.

Comment: This sounds like Access' "Filter by Form" feature.  If you're not aware of that, look into it.  If you are aware of it, please explain how your desired approach is different.

Comment: Hi HansUp! The difference between "Filter by Form" and what I'm looking for is that in the end the filtered query itself is displayed - not the filtered form... Does this make sense? I am looking to pass the data from the listboxes to feed into the query.

Comment: If you use a form whose recordsource is the query, not sure I understand that distinction.  Anyway, have you seen Allen Browne's [Search Criteria form](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html)?

Comment: Guess I'm lost.  Do you want to open the query in Datasheet View after selecting query criteria in text boxes on a form?

Comment: I'm still getting to grips with Access so I'm finding it difficult to articulate exactly what I'm looking for. The form has no record source - its unbound. The list boxes get their data from the tables (ie the row source). The query is separate to the form. In the end I just want to display the 'raw' data from the select query. Allen Browne's search criteria looks similar to what I require, the only difference is that the user needs to be able to search multiple data at once (for example: search for Jack, Dave, Tim etc. (via a list box) and return all these records (via the select query)).

Comment: Sorry, above is my updated comment. Yes, the end result is to have the query open in Datasheet view using the list boxes in the form to filter it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is you have a form with unbound multi-select list boxes and you want to open a query in Datasheet View and have that query based on the list box selections.

That means you must examine the `ItemsSelected` collection of each list box and update the query's `SQL` property accordingly.

On my test form, which includes a multi-select list box named *lstFname*, selecting the names *Jack, Dave, and Tim* in the list box, then clicking the command button (*cmdOpenQuery*), creates this `SELECT` statement.

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM Contacts AS c
WHERE c.fname IN ('Dave','Jack','Tim')
```

Then that statement is saved as the `SQL` property of a query named *qrySearchForm*.  And finally that query is opened in Datasheet View.

However my example includes only one list box, and you have several.  So you have more work ahead to extend this simple example.

Here is my form's code module ...

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit ' <- include this in ALL modules!

Private Sub cmdOpenQuery_Click()
    Const cstrQuery As String = "qrySearchForm"
    Dim strNames As String
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim varItm As Variant

    strSelect = "SELECT c.*" & vbCrLf & "FROM Contacts AS c"

    For Each varItm In Me.lstFname.ItemsSelected
        strNames = strNames & ",'" & _
            Me.lstFname.ItemData(varItm) & "'"
    Next varItm
    If Len(strNames) > 0 Then
        strNames = Mid(strNames, 2) ' discard leading comma
        strSelect = strSelect & vbCrLf & _
            "WHERE c.fname IN (" & strNames & ")"
    End If

    Debug.Print strSelect
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs(cstrQuery).Sql = strSelect
    DoCmd.OpenQuery cstrQuery
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, this looks good! :) I'll have a proper look tomorrow. I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant! I now have two listboxes working in tandem. For those looking for extra into I have strnames1, strnames2, strnames3 etc. Then for every iteration of the code I have replaced `"WHERE c.fname IN (" & strNames1 & ")` with `"AND c.fxxxx IN (" & strNamesx & ")"`.