# Synchronize two multi select combo boxes on a form in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I am working with two multi select combo boxes on an Access 2007 form. The first multi select combo box is a list of Diagnoses called `cboPatDX`. After the user selects any number of Diagnoses, I want to fill the next field called DXUnclear with just the selections made on `cboPatDX`. Most of the answers I have found online do not apply to the multi select combo box. Among many options I have tried, this is the latest, but I get a type **mismatch error**:

```
Me.cboDXUnclear.RowSource = "SELECT ID, Diagnosis FROM tblOptsWorkingDX WHERE ID = Me.cboPatDX ORDER BY Diagnosis"
Me.cboDXUnclear = Me.cboPatDX.ItemData(0)
```

I would appreciate any help with this, including other methods to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two links that might help you:

[filter a query based on multiple list boxes in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564501/filter-a-query-based-on-multiple-list-boxes-in-a-form)

https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/446193-filtering-query-values-multi-select-list-box