# Apply filters to an access query based on multiple selections in a listbox on a form

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to give users the ability to create lists of employees that work at multiple locations. I'm basically wanting to apply filters to the query through a form. If a user wants a list of people that work at location 1 and location 3, they would click those two boxes and output a list of people assigned to those locations. So, the filters would change based on how many locations they wanted to list.

I have a Query called "QryRosterRaw" which has the data from all locations. There is a column called "locations" that I want to filter. Just not sure how to apply the filters from the form.

I've looked at this:

[filter a query based on multiple list boxes in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564501/filter-a-query-based-on-multiple-list-boxes-in-a-form)

And can't seem to get it to work for my situation. Probably because I don't understand something in how it's updating the SQL on the query.

OK, back to basics. I now am simply trying to get the above referenced question to work for me at all and then apply it to my situation by having it construct my SQL for my problem. However, I can't even get that one to work.

I created a form and put in a button called "cmdOpenQuery" I also created a list box called "lstFname" with some random names in it as well as a query called "qrySearchForm". I copied the below code exactly into my form's code:

```
 Option Compare Database
 Option Explicit ' <- include this in ALL modules!

Private Sub cmdOpenQuery_Click()
Const cstrQuery As String = "qrySearchForm"
Dim strNames As String
Dim strSelect As String
Dim varItm As Variant

strSelect = "SELECT c.*" & vbCrLf & "FROM Contacts AS c"

For Each varItm In Me.lstFname.ItemsSelected
    strNames = strNames & ",'" & _
        Me.lstFname.ItemData(varItm) & "'"
Next varItm
If Len(strNames) > 0 Then
    strNames = Mid(strNames, 2) ' discard leading comma
    strSelect = strSelect & vbCrLf & _
        "WHERE c.fname IN (" & strNames & ")"
End If

Debug.Print strSelect
CurrentDb.QueryDefs(cstrQuery).Sql = strSelect
DoCmd.OpenQuery cstrQuery
End Sub
```

When I try to run the code, nothing happens to the query. The SQL statement is not updated and the query does not open. What am I doing wrong? I think if I can figure out how to make this work I can build my own custom statement for my situation, but I can't even make this one work.

Comment: The question above has been significantly edited from the original question. I could not make it work with the original method and this seemed like a simpler option (for me).

Comment: See edit of my answer.

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors. Please use these links: 1. [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) - to see what exactly happens when you click the button. -- 2. [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271) - to see if `strSelect` is constructed correctly (you have parts of this already in place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each varItm In Me.Locations.ItemsSelected  <---
    strNames = strNames & ",'" & _
        Me.lstFname.ItemData(varItm) & "'"  <---
Next varItm
```

You refer to different controls (`Locations` vs. `lstFname`) in your `For` loop. This won't work.

---

Edit for v2:

If you query is something like

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = Forms!myForm!mySelections
```

and `mySelections` is e.g. "1 or 3 or 5", this won't work. Access will compare the whole string.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ( Forms!myForm!mySelections )
```

with `mySelections` = "1,3,5" won't work either.

So I think your first approach (building the whole SELECT SQL from scratch) is the way to go.

Comment: Good catch. I have adjusted my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I have made a significant change above. I'm trying to approach the problem from a different angle as I didn't really understand what I was trying to do in the original method.

Comment: So, do I create the query in Access or does the VBA create it for me. Before when I was messing with it it didn't open the query and the SQL wasn't changed.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. However, when I tried to use the example (posted above) it didn't work. I think if I can get the example to work, I should be able to figure out how to re-write the code to fit my needs. However, I can't even get the example to work. Any advice now?

Answer (score 0):

It might be simple to set the *Filter* of the form:

```vb
For Each varItm In Me.lstFname.ItemsSelected
    strNames = strNames & ",'" & _
        Me.lstFname.ItemData(varItm) & "'"
Next varItm

If Len(strNames) > 0 Then
    strNames = Mid(strNames, 2) ' discard leading comma
    Me.Filter = "fName In (" & strNames & ")"
    Me.FilterOn = True
Else
    Me.FilterOn = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if i understood from your description, but  you have a form and you want to filter it via the listbox...
If this is the case then do this

```
Debug.Print strSelect ' Just Modifying your code from this point
Me.RecordSource = strSelect
Me.Requery
End Sub
```