# How to add items to a subform on the fly

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I have subform1 and a query1 with 4 fields as its recordSource. How do I add dynamically items I select from a listbox1 to my subform1 along with the 4 fields from query1. Basically, I want the 4 fields from my query1 plus any 1 or 2 items I select from my listbox1 to be displayed on subform1.

Something like this pseudo code :

```vb
subform1.datasource = query1 + listbox1.itemsSelected
```

I have 5 items on my listbox1 but my subform1 should only display what is selected on listbox1 plus the 4 items on query1.

Comment: Almost sure that this is possible. But it could be easier to create them already in design mode and show/hide them depending on whatever you need (eg content of the listbox)

Comment: That would probably be something along `mySubForm.Form!someProperty = myListBox.Column(2)`. Note you must a column for every needed property in the listbox. The column width can be 0 if you don't want to display it.

Comment: I thought about it @FunThomas but can't seem to find the way to hide/show columns based on items selected on my listbox. I know I can physically do it by right clicking on the desired columns I want to hide, however, I would like to do this with code (vba). Any hints?

Comment: How do you want to show the results on subform1? In the grid? In a listbox of its own?

Comment: @TheMortiestMorty , I want to show it in the grid. My subform1 is currently showing on my form but is showing all the fields from my listbox even though I didn't select them. I only want to show the ones the I select along with my other 4 fields from query1.

Comment: I am confused. You don't select fields of a listbox, you select items (rows, records). Selection of records in form should be determined by filter criteria. Perhaps you should show a mockup with tables in your question of what you want to produce.

Comment: I will put some screenshots together. @June7, I want  to display on my subform1 only the items selected from my listbox1.

Comment: If this is a multi-select listbox, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564501/filter-a-query-based-on-multiple-list-boxes-in-a-form

Comment: I would suggest working with a temperary table. Lets say : tzzSubform1. When you open the form you can delete * from tzzSubform1, when afterwards, you select something from your listbox, on the afterUpdate event you insert into tzzSubform1 (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) Values ( Listbox1.Value, QueryVal1,QueryVal2,QueryVal3) etc. When you select the above tzzSubform1 as datasource for the subform, the relevant records will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Are the items from this listbox to be included in the sub form the SAME table?

If yes, then all you require is to "combine" the criteria for the sub form query criteria, and then ALSO include the criteria of the items selected in the ListBox.

So, start out with the sub form query with the "first" or "starting" critera.

So, the code behind can look like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Dim strOriginalWhere        As String

Private Sub Form_Load()

    strOriginalWhere = "(ID IN (9,10))"
    
    Call LoadSubForm

End Sub


Sub LoadSubForm()

    Dim ExtraWhere      As String
    
    Dim vSel    As Variant
    Dim i       As Integer
    
    For i = 0 To Me.List0.ListCount - 1
    
        If Me.List0.Selected(i) Then
            If ExtraWhere <> "" Then ExtraWhere = ExtraWhere & ","
            ExtraWhere = ExtraWhere & Me.List0.Column(0, i)
            
        End If
            
    Next
    
    Dim strSQL      As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE " & strOriginalWhere
    
    If ExtraWhere <> "" Then
       strSQL = strSQL & " OR (ID IN (" & ExtraWhere & "))"
    End If
    
    strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY FirstName"
    
    Me.tblHotelsA4.Form.RecordSource = strSQL
    

End Sub

Private Sub List0_AfterUpdate()

    Call LoadSubForm

End Sub
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So, all we really are doing here is "adding" together the first criteria, and then adding to that the second criteria from each list box selection.